# I am trying to save the bibles.print("Gen", 1, 1) output to a text file. How do I do this?

Tags: python

from freebible import bibles

bibles.print("Gen", 1, 1)

My goal is to type a scripture and have the verse be saved into a text file

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is too vague, please add a code sample of what you have tried and where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your question as written doesn't make a whole ton of sense, but the title does, so I'll answer that instead. Here's how you can save the output of `bibles.print("Gen", 1, 1)` to a file:

```
from freebible import bibles

def save_to_file(book, chapter, verse, fname=None):
    if fname is None:
        fname = f'{book}_{chapter}_{verse}.txt'
    text = bibles.print(book, chapter, verse)
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
        # Change to f.write(str(text[0]) + '\n') if you want the Japanese text
        f.write(str(text[-1]) + '\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    save_to_file("Gen", 1, 1)
```

Script will save the text of the book to a file named `book`_`chapter`_`verse`.txt by default, or you can specify a filename if that doesn't suit your fancy. Function takes `book`, `chapter`, and `verse` as inputs. You can modify to make the script take these as command line arguments and pass it to the function above (if that's useful to you).

Example usage:

```
(so) Matthews-MacBook-Pro:bible matt$ ls
bible.py
(so) Matthews-MacBook-Pro:bible matt$ python bible.py 
[Ge 1:1] 元始に神天地を創造たまへり 
[Gen 1:1] In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.
(so) Matthews-MacBook-Pro:bible matt$ ls
Gen_1_1.txt bible.py
(so) Matthews-MacBook-Pro:bible matt$ cat Gen_1_1.txt 
[Gen 1:1] In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.
```

HTH.

Comment: Hey there so I got the output to save in a text file using another code!  I am now trying to get rid of all NON English words from the text file, but keep all of the punctuation.  I have been looking around, but cannot find exactly what I want.  Can you help me please??

Comment: @Bakari I think you're solving it backwards. Don't write the non-english to the file in the first place. Look at the output above, it's only the english version. Filtering out non-english from english in general is a really challenging problem (consider cognates)